# Return out of express route from inside mongoose callback when error

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying various ways of handling errors. If I have a setup to add a new document and I want to check that the name is unique, I do something like

```
router.route('/addSomething').post(async (req,res,next) => {
  await Document.findOne(
    {name: req.body.name}, // search parameter
    (error,doc) = { // callback
      if(error) return next(error) // pass system generated error to next() and exit route
      else if (doc) return next(new Error("This name already exists")) // pass my own error to next() and exit route
    })

  // everything from now on shouldn't happen

  await Document.save() etc...
```

The problem I'm having is that the route function continues even though an error has returned (I understand this is because the return statement only returns from the callback function).

I'm looking for an elegant way of handling mongoose/mongodb errors and exiting the function at point of error, without putting try/catch blocks everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

When you return `next(...)` inside your callback function you're not actually returning from the rest of your code, only inside that function. To fix this issue I have added a `continue()` function inside of your code to continue the incoming HTTP request.

```js
router.route('/addSomething').post(async (req, res, next) => {
    await Document.findOne(
        { name: req.body.name }, // search parameter
        (error, doc) => { // callback
            if (error) return next(error) // pass system generated error to next() and exit route
            else if (doc) return next(new Error("This name already exists")) // pass my own error to next() and exit route

            continue(); // Call the continue function if function isn't already returned
        }
    );
    function continue() { // Add a continue function
        // Continue your code
        await Document.save();
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: This is quite a neat solution but can get messy if I have more than one callback function in the code. I would need continue2(), continue3(), etc to handle subsequent callback instances

Comment: @EdwardMartin True however the only other way to do it is wrap your entire code in the callback, then you'd be causing [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to get rid of the callback:

```js
router.route('/addSomething').post(async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    var doc = await util.promisify(Document.findOne)(
      { name: req.body.name } // search parameter
    );
  } catch(error) {
    return next(error); // pass system generated error to next() and exit route
  }
  if (doc) return next(new Error("This name already exists")); // pass my own error to next() and exit route
  // everything from now on shouldn't happen
  await Document.save() etc...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Document.findOne() already returns a promise. I can use the .then and .catch methods but would rather not

Comment: If you use `await`, you need not use `.then` and `.catch`. Line 3 of my answer then simply becomes `var doc = await Document.findOne(`.

Comment: The question then is, how do I handle any error from that without wrapping it in a try/catch block.

Ideally I would be able to say var [error,doc] = await Document.findOne( in a similar way to the callback but I know this won't work!

Comment: Don't see how you could handle the error if you use neither `catch` nor `.catch`.

Comment: They can be handled using the findOne callback:  .findOne({},(error,doc) => ...) but the issue is that I can't exit the outer function within that callback